# Load framework ones to multiple bundles

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack, build, vuetify.js

I'm using Vue+Vuetify in every chunk for every HTML page, so my webpack configuration looks like this:

```js
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        main: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/widget_entry.js'),
        tg: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/tg.js'),
        connection: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/connection_s.js'),
        integration: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/integration_s.js'),
        payment: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/payment.js'),
        promotion: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/promotion.js'),
        waybill: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/waybill.js'),
        penalty: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/penalty.js'),
        fuelcard: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/fuelcard.js'),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, './dist'),
        filename: ({ chunk: { name } }) => {
            return name === 'main' ? '[name].bundle.js': '[name].[contenthash].js';
        },
    },

    module: {
        rules: [
            ...
        ],
    },
    resolve: {
        ...
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/waybill_frame.html'),
            filename: 'waybill.html',
            chunks : ['waybill']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/connection_s.html'), 
            filename: 'connection.html',
            chunks : ['connection']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/integration_s.html'),
            filename: 'integration.html',
            chunks : ['integration']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/promotion_frame.html'),
            filename: 'promotion.html', 
            chunks : ['promotion']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/payment_frame.html'),
            filename: 'payment.html', 
            chunks : ['payment']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/penalty_frame.html'),
            filename: 'penalty.html', // название выходного файла
            chunks : ['penalty']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/tg_frame.html'),
            filename: 'tg.html',
            chunks : ['tg']
        }),
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/fuelcard_frame.html'),
            filename: 'fuelcard.html',
            chunks : ['fuelcard']
        }),
    ],
}
```

Because I'm importing Vue and Vuetify in every JavaScript file, budnle files is too large and it takes very long time to load the page.

**How can I import Vue+Vuetify in one bundle file and use it in all my HTML pages?**

Comment: You can use webpack externals to indicate that Vue and Vuetify is on the window. Then you must import them in the html so they will actually be available

Comment: Why do you use so much entry points and not dynamic import for example? What is the structure of the app that requires this design?